# Instantiated object is local so I can't delete it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have an instantiated object in an `if` statement, but I want to destroy it in another `if` statement.

This is impossible due to the fact that the object is local, so I can't reference it outside of the if statement. How can I fix this?

Also, I want to destroy every object that was instantiated in the for loop. These instantiated objects are just there for inventory purposes, though that's not very relevant to the question.

I just want to delete all of the objects when I stop pressing the `r` button.

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
    {
        slotPos = new Vector3(camPos.position.x - 4.5f, camPos.position.y + (13 / 2), -6);
        row = 0;
        rowColumn = 0; //dont worry about this

        for (; row > 10;)
        {
            GameObject invenPlace = Instantiate(slot); //local object
            invenPlace.transform.position = new Vector3(slotPos.x + row, slotPos.y, -6);

            row = row + 1;
            rowColumn = rowColumn + 1;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("r") == false)
    {
        DestroyObject(invenPlace); //trying to destroy local object
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it's a locally declared variable, it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @fredrik It won't disappear from the Unity scene though, that's different.

Comment: You are instantiating the 'local object' in a loop, but you are trying to 'destroy' just one of the instances. Are you trying to delete all instantiations of `invenPlace`?

Comment: Then there is only one option, move the declaration so that it is visible where you want to destroy it.

Comment: You are creating a whole bunch of them

Comment: You also have an infinite loop there since you only increase `row` so it probably will always stay `>10` once reached ... Please post your actual code as a minimal working coding example ...

Comment: You do realize that `(13 / 2)` will evaluate to `6` and not `6.5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to stash them in a list in e.g. the component's instance variables.

Another possibility is to instantiate them as children of one empty parent GameObject you can then destroy.

```
private List<GameObject> invenPlaces = new List<GameObject>();

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
    {
        for (; row > 10;)
        {
            GameObject invenPlace = Instantiate(slot); //local object
            // ...
            invenPlaces.Add(invenPlace);
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("r") == false)
    {
        foreach (var invenPlace in invenPlaces) {
            DestroyObject(invenPlace);
        }
        invenPlaces.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Clarification that using field is important due to nature of the code (key generally can't be up and down at the same time during single method call may be useful (also can be considered offensive :) )

Answer (score -1):

How about initiating the object in the begining of the function so it is available through the whole scope? Ojects are reachable only in the scope they are declared in, so you need to make it either global for the function scope, or maybe global for the whole class it belongs to. Try this.

```
void Update()
    {
    GameObject invenPlace = null;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {

            slotPos = new Vector3(camPos.position.x - 4.5f, camPos.position.y + (13 / 2), -6);

            row = 0; 
            rowColumn = 0; //dont worry about this
            

            for (;row > 10 ;)
            {

                invenPlace = Instantiate(slot); //local object
                invenPlace.transform.position = new Vector3(slotPos.x + row, slotPos.y, -6); 

                row = row + 1;
                rowColumn = rowColumn + 1;

                

            }

        }

        if (Input.GetKey("r") == false)
        {
            DestroyObject(invenPlace); //trying to destroy local object
        }


    }
```